# Size of unknown container

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style, std

I have always been reading that using this code is not so good:

```
std::vector<T> my_vector;
...
std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end());
```

It is better to write it as:

```
std::vector<T> my_vector;
...
std::sort(std::begin(my_vector), std::end(my_vector));
```

Because std::begin will work with all containers including normal arrays.

What is the alternative to `my_vector.size()` that will work for all containers including normal arrays?

Comment: You could try rolling your own templated `size()` function, and specialize for raw c-style arrays.

Comment: std::size but until C++ 17

Comment: You will get a `std::size(my_vector)` in C++17. Right now there isn't any.

Comment: YMMV, but I would stop worrying about supporting all container types: You need only exactly four containers: `vector<>`, `unordered_map<>`, `deque<>`, and `unordered_set<>` in this order. Of these, only the `vector<>` is the general work-horse, the others are only useful in special situations. Most importantly, you should never use a `list<>` or `forward_list<>`, these can be replaced by a `vector<>` in all cases, and the `vector<>` will be significantly faster. That is, well over 90% of your containers should be `vector<>`, and the special cases are, well, special anyway.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually using `std::begin(my_vector)` is *not* the Right Thing! If you want to pick up the customization point you'd rather use

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;
std::sort(begin(cont), end(cont));
```

This approach tries to find `begin(cont)` using ADL and, when failing to locate a suitable versio, fallback to use `std::begin`.

Sadly, there is no `std::size` being the default for a customization point like `std::begin`. It would sort of work to use `std::distance()`:

```
std::distance(begin(cont), end(cont));
```

However, for typical node-based containers or, more generally, for non-random access iterators this approach would walk the elements rather then obtaining the size from a stored value. Thus, I'd think you'd want to call `cont.size()`. It would be relatively straight forward to define a suitable customization point:

```
namespace util {
    template <typename C>
    typename C::difference_type size(C const& c) {
        return c.size();
    }
    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    std::size_t size(T const(&)[N]) {
        return N;
    }
}
```

As was pointed out in comments, a non-member `size()` function was added to the [working paper for C++17](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4431.pdf) (see the bottom of the synopsis in 24.3 [iterator.synoposis]). [N4280](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4280.pdf) is the paper which proposed the change. This paper also proposes functions `empty()` and `data()` which were also added. All of these functions are declared in `<iterator>`.

The version added to C++17 uses a `decltype()` on the `size()` member directly in the return type. In addition it declares the function to be `constexpr`:

```
template <typename C>
constexpr auto size(C const& c) -> decltype(c.size()) {
    return c.size();
}
```

Comment: They should be two different  answers so I can vote up twice.. thanks you made it clear for me.

Comment: [`std::size` will appear in C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)